# Voice recognition libraries - C++

Tags: c++, sound, voice

I need to implement voice recognition in my game, the target is that the user speaks into the microphone and the game responds accordingly to some commands.

What libraries could help me with such task? I need them for C++ and as lightweight as possible to plug into the game(it will be used in mobile games).

An ideal usage would be having it capture input sound or receiving the audio samples, and outputting strings with the recognized text.

Thanks

Comment: Which tech to use (and questions that generate lists) are off topic on GDSE according to the FAQ.

Comment: You are right, however I couldn't really ask on particular implementation techniques since I have no illusions of making it myself :p

Answer (score 1):

Voice recognition is more difficult than you think it is. At least, you need dictionary (file containing thousands of words). Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817663/sound-sample-recognition-library-code

Comment: A game probably would need only a few dozen words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google voice recognition with Android device. You can also setup a server and send the voice recognition request to Google's server for device such as iOS. It requires internet connection but it provides the best result. The encoded audio file is small so the latency is minimal.

Since you only has a few hundred words you can also try [Sphinx3](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) and [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/).

Dragon Speech Recognition is an option but it requires commercial license. Dictionary can be provided for better result.